# How to use flurry in an application?

Tags: android, flurry

I would like to use flurry and its features in my application. How can i register myself with flurry and how can i use it in my android application?

Thanks

Comment: Pls refer this http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2010/01/discovering-flurry.html ,this will giude you

Comment: but after registering with flurry what code i have to write in my android application for it. steps and jar file that i have to use after registering with flurry is provided to me at time of registration or i have to search it myself

Comment: As non registered user don't have access to the API and documentation, I suggest you should do what everyone of us would have to do: dig into the documentation and try it yourself

Comment: Where i can find API and documentation regarding flurry

Comment: @Nikki: you have to register in flurry,create an account, with your login you are able to find API and documentation, Nikki

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's actually really simple.

1 - Head to flurry.com and register for your app, which will generate a unique tracking code.

2 - Download and add the FlurryAgent jar to your project libraries. If you're using Eclipse, right-click your project folder, select properties, select Java Build Path, and choose Add External JARs.. or use Gradle + Jcenter `compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.2.0'`

3 - Add `android.permission.INTERNET` to your AndroidManifest.xml.

4 - Add a call to the Flurry agent from the onStart() and onStop methods of your activities.

Note: replace the ID below with your unique tracking code.

```
public void onStart()
{
   super.onStart();
   FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "9GKQD4EBX123FEP6874H");
   // your code
}

public void onStop()
{
   super.onStop();
   FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
   // your code
}
```

That's it!

Comment: From the Flurry dashboard, under Manage Applications click Add a New Application. Next select the application's platform,enter the application name and category, and finally hit Create App. This will take you to a screen showing you the API key.

Comment: If you are referring to an existing app, select the app then go to Manage.

Comment: Just to confirm - am I right that you add the above code to every Activity within your app?

Comment: and you can call FlurryAgent.logEvent methods to log events during a session ,I recommend official document of flurry  http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android

Comment: @KyleClegg Is this necessary to download sdk for each new application? Or just use previous jar file and change apk key?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde you can reuse the jar, I'd just be sure you're not missing out on an update when you do.

Comment: @KyleClegg where we use ad unit id in coding. here you use only API key.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following methods (during a session only) to report additional data:

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId)
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, boolean timed)
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, Map<String, String> parameters)
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, Map<String, String> parameters, boolean timed)
```

Comment: where this code to be enter in onstart on in onresume and I also want to know that how can i get the error reports and which codeis added to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Steps by steps use Flurry Analytics.

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/TechnicalQuickStart/Android