# I want to track complete information about the usage of my android application

Tags: android, android-activity, backtracking

I want to track complete information about the usage of my android application Right from the time the user starts to use my application.

Like I want to track all the activities which the user has gone through and the datas he/she entered too. I want to send those datas as screenshots or something to my server.

What my aim is to find ways to track all these and send it to a server..

Pls suggest some implementation ideas

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So, something like a spy app? You collect info about users without them knowing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an analytics library like Flurry and Google Analytics. These will allow you to track your users app usage, and you can send custom events which will contain the data your users are entering.

Screenshots cannot be taken. This is a security risk.

Tracking this level of detail would be a concern for a lot of users. Make sure you inform them of what you are doing either in your app description or when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

You should trying looking up Flurry or Google Analytics for tracking events, and activities, etc.

As for the screenshots, if there was a simple way to get a screenshot without the user knowing (and I'm pretty sure there isn't), I'm don't think your users would appreciate apps constantly sending images on their connection without their knowing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Logging database using SQLite that logs the activities along with some userID.

You can then have this DB periodically sent to your server via http where it's co-opted into a larger stats database.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this for that you can integrate flurry in your application

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460566/how-to-use-flurry-in-an-application

 http://www.flurry.com/
```

i think flurry is the best way to full fill your requirment

first sign up to flurry then login in it after that flurry pdf will guide you for all application tracking it is very easy i am using it and find it very accurate and fine

Comment: also read this 
http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2010/01/discovering-flurry.html

Comment: Why flurry is "the best"? When you say best, you better mention some others and compare