# Flurry: if flurry events added without start/end session, will it show on flurry site?

Tags: android, session, flurry

> If flurry events are added in an activity without adding startsession
>   / endsession in onStart/onStop will it log on the flurry site

?
Previous activity is having startsession / endsession in its onStart/onStop.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flurry will not consider an activity if it doesn't have a call to onStartSession. So long as there is any Context that has called onStartSession but not onEndSession, the session will be continued. This also means that Events will not be logged for that particular activity.

(Full disclosure: I work at Flurry)

Comment: thnks.what about this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211814/what-is-this-uncaught-seen-in-event-list-in-flurry-site

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, no! If you are not starting a session then the server side won't know to which session to added that specific event to.

What I mean by that is that is that `Flurry` does not have indication of the the user details if there was not session created.

```
Previous activity is having startsession / endsession in onStart/onStop
```

The fact the previous activity does have does method doesn't change anything because as you start Flurry session in this activity in `onStart` you end it in `onStop`. so the session does not continue to exist in the following activity.

Comment: that means it wont log the events in portal in that case?