# What is this "uncaught" seen in event list in flurry site?

Tags: android, flurry, uncaught-exception

In flurry site, in Event logs session instead of events sometimes

> "uncaught"

is showing .Can anyone tell *what does it means*?
Is it any error from app side? [all events are displayed in site but in some sessions it shows one or two events then uncaught]

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the latest Flurry SDK version, which has the errors beta enabled, then the uncaught would appear under event logs, which is normal.

Comment: ya i am using the latest one.what is this 'uncaught' means?

Comment: 'Uncaught' refers to the exceptions thrown in your app.

Comment: @AmanBansal thanks. So that means exception occurred in event logging?or parameters getting null? or other app exceptions?

Comment: I want to disable the catching of any exception in Flurry. I just want to log events in Flurry, How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set  `setCaptureUncaughtExceptions` as **false** where you're configuring flurry :

```
FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(false);
```

From flurry doc:

> Used to allow/disallow Flurry SDK to report uncaught exceptions. The
>   feature is enabled by default, and if you would like to disable this
>   behavior, this must be called before calling init.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem was when I used `FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(false);` (I thought that this call disables logging output to the android adb log). Instead this call turns off event logging in Flurry Web Interface.

So just remove `FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(false)` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed an error in your app. An exception is raised, and you are not catching it. To know what is going on, you need to log uncaught exceptions to Flurry as well. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udoIUlqzZC4) explains how to do so.