# Flurry - timed event questions

Tags: android, flurry

I have some questions related to timed events from Flurry:

1). If I'm using `logEvent (String eventId, boolean timed)` to log a timed event and never call `endTimedEvent(String)`, what will happen with this event ? Will it ever be logged  - maybe at the end of the session ?

2). If I call once `logEvent (String eventId, boolean timed)` and twice `endTimedEvent(String)` what will happen with the second `endTimedEvent` call?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Flurry iOS 4.3.0 documentation](http://support.flurry.com/sdkdocs/iOS/v4.3/interface_flurry.html#ab72c8c091057d2b60786a29d2767e99c):

> If the app is backgrounded prior to ending a timed event, the Flurry SDK will automatically end the timer on the event.
> endTimedEvent:withParameters: is ignored if called on a previously terminated event.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a temporary event and try both of these. I assume that the first event will not get logged if the event is never ended. Similarly, I'd guess that the second event would only be logged once and not twice.