# How to add new Flurry Analytics in Android?

Tags: android, yahoo, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have been trying to use Flurry Analytics with the official documentation but I am not getting it. As answered in the question here: [How to use flurry in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460566/how-to-use-flurry-in-an-application) I used

```
import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgent;
@Override
protected void onStart()
 {
 super.onStart();
  FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "YOUR_API_KEY");
 }
@Override
 protected void onStop()
{
super.onStop();
FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
  }
```

But the above code seems to be deprecated, the official documentation says to use

```
 //If you are shipping an app, extend the Application class if you are not already doing so:

 public class MyApplication extends Application {
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
// configure Flurry
FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(false);

// init Flurry
FlurryAgent.init(this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY);
 }
}
```

What is meant by shipping an app?
How to integrate new Flurry analytics? Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous versions of Flurry analytics required adding a line of code to each Activity in your app - in the onStart() and onStop() methods:
    
    `@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Start Flurry
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, );
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        // stop Flurry
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
        super.onStop();
    }`
    
The latest version of Flurry simplifies this by having you add a single line of code to the Application class of your app - so if you don't have an application class (and for most apps it is probably not needed) you will have to create one:
    
    `public class CKApplication extends Application {`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // configure flurry...

    // init Flurry
    FlurryAgent.init(this, MY_FLURRY_APIKEY);
}
</code>
```

"Shipping" and app means submitting it to Google Play store - or any other app store - in other words making your app available to the public is called "shipping the app".